# Auto Height Sidebar with respect to the content area CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, xhtml, scrollbar

I have a CSS height adjustment problem, the height of the sidebar or the content should be aligned to each other, like .left-section have 500 height but now the content area isn't aligned to the height of the left section due to the left section has a top section (red top area) which content can grow, so I can't work with margin or padding on the list section, is there any solution for it?

https://jsfiddle.net/e548zLjt/

Problem Screenshot
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style type="text/css">
    ul,ol {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
    .left-section {height: 500px;display:block;}
    .content-area {background: #ccc;}
    .top-section  {background: #ff0000;}
    .list-section  {background: #ffff00;overflow: auto;max-height: 100%}
    .list-section li {height: 100px;background: #eee;width: 100%;display: block;border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="wrapper main-cont">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4 left-section">
          <div class="top-section">
            <h1>This is Top Section</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Search</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-section">
            <ul>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 content-area text-center">
          <p>Can we make either content area or left section to have equal bottom end without providing separate height values to left section and the content area? can we have single value height adjust for them? right now list is bigger than the content area</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your code like below. Simply add `d-flex flex-column` to the left section

```css
ul,
ol {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.left-section {
  height: 500px;
}

.content-area {
  background: #ccc;
}

.top-section {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.list-section {
  background: #ffff00;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%
}

.list-section li {
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="wrapper main-cont">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-4 left-section d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="top-section">
          <h1>This is Top Section</h1>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Search</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-section">
          <ul>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
            <li>A List Item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 content-area text-center">
        <p>Can we make either content area or left section to have equal bottom end without providing separate height values to left section and the content area? can we have single value height adjust for them? right now list is bigger than the content
          area</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is just perfect, does it support all the browsers including IE 11? Thanks

Comment: @MZH yes it does, I am not using anything fancy. A simple flexbox configuration. Boostrap V4 is using flexbox anyway so if something will break, it's all the page not only what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem just add `.left-section { overflow: overlay; }`  to the left section

```css
ul,
ol {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.left-section {
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
}

.content-area {
  background: #ccc;
}

.top-section {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.left-section {
  overflow: overlay;
}

.list-section {
  background: #ffff00;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%
}

.list-section li {
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper main-cont">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4 left-section">
          <div class="top-section">
            <h1>This is Top Section</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Search</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-section">
            <ul>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 content-area text-center">
          <p>Can we make either content area or left section to have equal bottom end without providing separate height values to left section and the content area? can we have single value height adjust for them? right now list is bigger than the content
            area</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want the scrollbar on the list only, not on the full left panel, the top red section will remain on top, the list is scrollable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All I did is below-

```
.left-section {
  /* replaced height: 500px; with this */
  height: calc(100vh - 5px);
  /* and added this */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* and removed display: block; no need for that */
}

.list-section {
  background: #ffff00;
  overflow: auto;
  /* replaced max-height: 100% with this */
  height: 100vh;
}
```

After these changes with all your provided code, this is the snippet I got, **only the lists are scrolling on the left panel and the red section remains on top**, hope it would help-

**open the snippet in full screen because you used `col-md-*` so you can't see the demo properly if you don't open it in full screen*

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style type="text/css">
    ul,ol {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
    .content-area {background: #ccc;}
    .top-section  {background: #ff0000;}
    .left-section {height: calc(100vh - 5px); overflow: hidden}
    .list-section  {background: #ffff00;overflow: auto;height: 100%; margin-bottom: auto}
    .list-section li {height: 100px;background: #eee;width: 100%;display: block;border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
  </style>

  <div class="wrapper main-cont">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4 left-section">
          <div class="top-section">
            <h1>This is Top Section</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Search</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-section">
            <ul>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
              <li>A List Item</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 content-area text-center">
          <p>Can we make either content area or left section to have equal bottom end without providing separate height values to left section and the content area? can we have single value height adjustemphasized text for them? right now list is bigger than the content area</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```